# AFNetworking and Background Transfer service : Upload

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm using the following to upload a file in background.

Problem is that the completionhandler is not called after the file is uploaded.
(I can confirm that file is indeed uploaded in the server side)

I have this in my pod file.

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

And the code is..

```
NSString* apiUrl = @"http://example.com/upload";

// Prepare a temporary file to store the multipart request prior to sending it to the server due to an alleged
// bug in NSURLSessionTask.
NSString* tmpFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
NSURL* tmpFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFilename]];

// Create a multipart form request.
NSMutableURLRequest *multipartRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                                                   URLString:apiUrl
                                                                                                  parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                         {
                                             [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]
                                                                        name:@"file"
                                                                    fileName:fileName
                                                                    mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
                                         } error:nil];

// Dump multipart request into the temporary file.
[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMultipartFormRequest:multipartRequest
                                          writingStreamContentsToFile:tmpFileUrl
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                                                        // Once the multipart form is serialized into a temporary file, we can initialize
                                                        // the actual HTTP request using session manager.

                                                        // Create default session manager.
                                                        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

                                                        // Show progress.
                                                        NSProgress *progress = nil;
                                                        // Here note that we are submitting the initial multipart request. We are, however,
                                                        // forcing the body stream to be read from the temporary file.
                                                        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:multipartRequest
                                                                                                                   fromFile:tmpFileUrl
                                                                                                                   progress:&progress
                                                                                                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error)
                                                                                              {
                                                                                                  // Cleanup: remove temporary file.
                                                                                                  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:tmpFileUrl error:nil];

                                                                                                  // Do something with the result.
                                                                                                  if (error) {
                                                                                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                                                                                  } else {
                                                                                                      NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
                                                                                                  }
                                                                                              }];

                                                        // Add the observer monitoring the upload progress.
                                                        [progress addObserver:self
                                                                   forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
                                                                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                                                      context:NULL];

                                                        // Start the file upload.
                                                        [uploadTask resume];
                                                    }];
```

The last completionhandler where I delete the temporary file is not called.

Answer (score 0):

This init is for Default sessions:

```
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
```

For background session, you should use:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:kBackgroundSessionId];
```